# Entity Framework Core 6 detaches newly added entity

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-core

Hello dear StackOverflow community,

i have recently begun working on a project with Entity Framework Core 6. It's a very neat framework and after few little hiccups i got used to it quickly.

However i've found out that Entity Framework secretly detaches newly created objects sometimes.

I'm working on a software which connects to cameras with integrated license plate recognition software, loads the license plates and additional data and later checks, how long a car remained on the parking lot. I store them in a table for currently parked cars as well as a table for statistics. Once i processed all license plates, i write them to the database to be later checked for parking violations.

The cars make it to the database fine, however some of the statistics are not written in there. According to the EF logs, Entity Framework is missing a reference to the parking lot or the camera the car got scanned with and thus EF detaches my statistics object. However Entity Framework does not throw an error and according to the debugger, the camera and parking lot objects are present and the statistics object got the reference.

You can find the code below.

Thank you in advance for your time to help me :)

```cs
List<Cars> cars = new List<Cars>();

foreach (Camera cam in _parkingLot.Cameras)
{
    ICamera cameraObject = ICamera.GetCameraObjekt(cam);

    //Loading all license plates from the camera
    List<Cars> tempCars = cameraObject.GetCars();

    cars.AddRange(tempCars);
}

//Adds new cars to current context
_context.AddRange(cars);

foreach (Cars car in cars)
{
    //Saving some additional information
    //since i do not look immediately for
    //potential violations and want to make
    //sure that i do not apply rules retroactively
    ParkTimes parkTimes = GetParkTimes(car);
    ParkTimes rentTimes = GetRentTimes(car);

    if (parkTimes != null)
    {
        car.ParkStartTime = parkTimes.StartTime;
        car.ParkEndTime = parkTimes.EndTime;
    }

    if (rentTimes != null)
    {
        car.RentStartTime = rentTimes.StartTime;
        car.RentEndTime = rentTimes.EndTime;
    }

    //Here's where i save my statistics
    ParkStatistics stats = new ParkStatistics();

    stats.Direction = Convert.ToInt32(car.Direction);
    stats.Car = car;
    stats.Timestamp = car.Timestamp;

    //The camera is attached to the car after creating the car object
    //after i downloaded the data from the camera. This one is allegedly missing.
    stats.Camera = car.Camera;
    stats.CameraName = car.Camera.Name;

    //We're in a class here and the _parkingLot property is
    //a global property. This one is also allegedly missing.
    stats.ParkingLot = _parkingLot;

    stats.HasRentingService = _parkingLot.HasRentingService;
    stats.HasParkingMeter = _parkingLot.HasParkingMeter;
    stats.MaxParkingDuration = _parkingLot.MaxParkingDuration;

    if (parkTimes != null)
    {
        stats.ParkStartTime = parkTimes.StartTime;
        stats.ParkEndTime = parkTimes.EndTime;
    }

    if (rentTimes != null)
    {
        stats.RentStartTime = rentTimes.StartTime;
        stats.RentEndTime = rentTimes.EndTime;
    }

    //When i add the statistics object to the context,
    //the object gets detached. I do not get an exception
    //here. I only realized that the object is missing
    //after looking at the database and reading
    //the EF logs.
    _context.Add(stats);
}

_parkingLot.LastUpdate = DateTime.Now;

_context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Can you please provide a full [mre]?

Comment: Are you monitoring memory pressure whilst executing your task? It's possible, if EF is still using weak references anywhere, that things are getting garbage collected if .NET thinks it's low on memory. Instead of trying to load everything in memory at once to process it have you considered trying to use stream processing (I'm assuming, of course, that all of your `Get` methods support `IEnumerable`)?

Comment: @AlwaysLearning As far as i've observed, the memory usage never rose beyond 64 megabytes (which i think is odd). Unless that is my memory limit, i believe that everything is a-ok.

EDIT: I forgot to mention that my project is a C# Worker project. Perhaps that could also be relevant.